# How to observe a key path like "object.attribute"

Tags: cocoa, avaudioplayer, key-value, addobserver

greetings , I'm a cocoa beginner and this is my first post:P

I'm trying to make a very simple rhythm game but get stuck , here's what I got:

```
/**** TouchView.h/m ****/
@property AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;
```

---

```
[self addObserver:self 
       forKeyPath:@"audioPlayer.currentTime" 
          options:(NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew | NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld)
          context:NULL];
```

---

```
//audioPlayer.currentTime's type is NSTimeinterval (double)

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change (NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
   NSLog(@"action triggered!")
}
```

which doesn't work (I have initialized audioPlayer properly,it can play sound but just can't be caught when its currentTime value changes)

I test these code with another property "double testNumber" , set it as the argument of "keyPath" , increase it by one when I touch the screen , then that works well. But what should I do to make audioPlayer.currentTime can be observed , I just want to get notified when this value changed , any other advice will also be appreciated. I'm counting on you , please help me ,thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
[audioPlayer addObserver:self
              forKeyPath:@"currentTime"
                 options:(NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew | NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld)
                 context:NULL];
```

However if you really want to make **your** object KVC-compliant (which is what you're attempting to use), you need to follow [Apple's guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/Compliant.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002172-BAJEAIEE) on the subject:

> In order for a class to be considered KVC compliant for a specific
>   property, it must implement the methods required for valueForKey: and
>   setValue:forKey: to work for that property.

Comment: Thanks for the info,though the trick doesn't work either XD. Maybe it's because when currentTime changes automatically, accessor methods(set/get/valueForkey/setValueForKey) do not even get called. I add setValueForKey:@"currentTime" in -(void)touchesBegin: , then when I touch the screen , observer's action is triggered, so I think this property is KVC compliant. Now my thought is to observe another value which is assigned to the value of currentTime , use a while loop tracking the currentTime's value until music finished , but wherever I put it,app will be blocked within it

Comment: So I want to try something on NSThread , hoping that will help , otherwise I'll have to look into other sound engines like OpenAL or FMOD... which will lead a much harder life :( anyway , thanks again for your answer,I learned something through it